# Behavior of return/enter key

Tags: notepad++

In some of my notepad++ files, hitting the Enter key yields a carriage return (CR) *and* a line feed (LF), while in other files, it yields only a line feed.

I have not been able to find any rule of thumb for how a certain file will behave.
What determines the behavior and how I can I control it ?

Answer (score 5):

It depends where your files come from.

End of line is

- `\n` for Unix/Linux files
- `\r\n` for Windows files
- `\r` for old Mac files

---

Thanks to David Postill,

If you want to modify EOL in the open files:

`Menu Edit >> EOL Conversion >>`

Choose the  one you want in Windows or Unix or Mac

Comment: Well, yes, but actually no. It's as @JeffZeitlin said. It detects the line ending and keeps using it. Except when you create a new file, where you can just go to "Settings" > "Preferences" > "New Document" > "Windows".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You could post this answer separately.

Answer (score 2):

The ‘default’ rule is to look at the existing file and continue to use whatever EOL character it finds. Per [Toto’s answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1770497/behavior-of-return-enter-key/1770498#1770498), you can set the EOL conversion (and therefore the EOL character that will be used); the ‘standard’ EOL characters are as stated in that answer - `0x0A` for Unix/Linux (and probably FreeBSD and current Mac), `0x0D` for older Mac files, and `0x0D 0x0A` for Windows/MS-DOS (inherited from CP/M).

The actual origin of the file is irrelevant; I tested this by using a hex editor to create a text file in Windows that used `0x0A` as the EOL character, and when I opened it in Notepad++, it continued to use `0x0A` as the EOL character.